# Vector perpendicular to A

Tags: vectors

Hi! I have attempted all the questions represented below but I do not know how to do number F otherwise the rest was not that big of a challenge. Would appreciate the help thanks

> Given $\vec{a}=[2,3,7]$ and $\vec{b}=[-3,4,-1]$, find
>
> $\quad\text{a.}$ $|2\vec{a}|$
>
> $\quad\text{b.}$ $3\vec{a}-4\vec{b}$
>
> $\quad\text{c.}$ The angle between $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{a}$.
>
> $\quad\text{d.}$ A unit vector in the direction of $\vec{b}$
>
> $\quad\text{e.}$ $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}$
>
> $\quad\text{f.}$ A vector perpendicular to $\vec{a}$.
>
> $\quad\text{g.}$ The vector projection of $\vec{b}$ on $\vec{a}$.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would search three $a,b,c$ such that $(a,b,c)\cdot\mathbf{\vec{a}}=0$. For example, $$a=0,b=-7,c=+3$$ See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You need to find a vector $\bar c = (x,y,z)$ that satisfies the property

$$\bar c \cdot \bar a = (x,y,z) \cdot (2,3,7) = 0$$

For this, obviously, there are many solutions! Just guess some values that fit for $(x,y,z)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: take any point in the plane $2x+3y+7z=0$. Can you see why the vector $(x,y,z)$ is perpendicluar to $\bar a$?